# Redirect with Array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8, if I want to redirect to named route I can use:

```
return redirect()->route( 'success' )->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

It will always redirect "status" with the value of "Profile updated!" which I can then display in my view with:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

But how can I pass an ***array*** using redirect()->route() instead of just a single value?

Comment: Have you tried `->with('status', [1, 2, 3]);` or something like `->with('status', 'Profile updated!')->with('array', [1, 2, 3]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L42) is how it is implemented:

```
/**
 * Flash a piece of data to the session.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function with($key, $value = null)
{
    $key = is_array($key) ? $key : [$key => $value];

    foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
        $this->session->flash($k, $v);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

It means you can just pass an array as the first argument, that's all.

```
return redirect()->route( 'success' )->with(['foo' => 'bar']);
```